# Make transition from AR to non AR

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am making a top-down strategy game using Vuforia and want to make transition to fps mode. The problem is that as soon as I take my camera away from image target,my environment disppears and the game freezes. I have tried changing the parent of all the objects from image target to another object,switching the camera,but no luck. This is the code that i have used to switch cameras.

```
void change(){
      cams [c%2].GetComponent <Camera> ().enabled = false;
     cams[(c+1)%2].GetComponent <Camera> ().enabled = true;
     if (c % 2 == 1) {
         scene.transform.parent = imageTarget.transform;
     } else {
         scene.transform.parent = transform;
      }
     c++;
 }
```

I want to use the rotation of AR-camera as the rotation of my non-AR-camera so that user can see around in the scene by turning the AR-camera(similar to vr style but without vr headset).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to first of all use **Extended Tracking** (option under the **ARCamera** in your scene).

If you want to get an fps view you could enlarge all the children (objects) of your **Image Target** in such a way that they are close to room-scale. By doing that you don't have to switch cameras and with the **Extended Tracking** enabled, you can look around and view the enlarged environment.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,I got that working.I did use extended tracking but instead of enlarging the objects,I made everything a child of an empty gameobject (not a child of imagetarget),then i turned off camera component of the ARCamera and turned it on for other camera(attached with the player).Hence i was able to switch from AR to fps mode.